# Today extension target membership causes an error No Such Module

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, today-extension

I am trying to implement today extension named WaitingWorkOrders for my application. I have added target from my workspace then I would like to use my generic NetworkRequest class and xib view that I am using for another view controller from my today extension. However, whenever I tick my target membership from NetworkRequest class, No such module 'Alamofire' error. I also added libraries into my podfile using following technique;

[image: My target memberships]

> https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2017/07/09/swift-3-extensions-ios-today-widget/

How can I solve that problem so that I can use my reusable xib and NetworkRequest class?

Comment: Post some code. You're not providing enough information for us to help you.

Comment: If there would be any code snippet I'd like to share but it is the problem with targets and pods @onnoweb